# BIRT reports and IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, birt

I have a similar problem - i was trying to run this code for IntelliJ Idea 13 and i would like to use rptdesign file to generate the report. The code looks like this:

```java
public class ExecuteBIRTReport {
    static void executeReport() throws EngineException {

        EngineConfig config = null;
        IReportEngine engine = null;
        try {
            config = new EngineConfig();
            config.setLogConfig("/logs", java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);

            Platform.startup(config);
            IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                    .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
            engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
            IReportRunnable report = null;
            String reportFilepath = "C://Users//user//workspace//TestProject//Products.rptdesign";
            try {
                report = engine.openReportDesign(reportFilepath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Report " + reportFilepath + " not found!\n");
                engine.destroy();
                return;
            }

            IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);

            PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
            options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
            options.setOutputFileName("C:/Users/user/workspace/TestProject/REPORT.pdf");

            task.setRenderOption(options);

            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (EngineException e1) {
                System.err.println("Report " + reportFilepath + " run failed.\n");
                System.err.println(e1.toString());
            }
            engine.destroy();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            executeReport();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I imported the project IntelliJ following jar-files (without them do not eceive a compilation):

```
com.ibm.icu_54.1.1.v201501272100.jar
org.eclipse.birt.core_4.5.0.v201506092134.jar
org.eclipse.birt.data_4.5.0.v201506092134.jar
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter_4.5.0.v201506092134.jar
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine_4.5.0.v201506092134.jar
org.eclipse.birt.report.model_4.5.0.v201506092134.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723.jar
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.4.3.v201405301249.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857.jar
```

In Eclipse version of BIRT 4.5.0. and a report is created normally. In IntelliJ at the stage of creating a file error message:The output format <...> is not supported. I tried to arrange for the withdrawal of pdf and html formats, but to no avail. Does anyone know a solution?